# Is there a good way to iterate over these different indexes effectively?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am currently making a connect4 game, and for the board I am using a String array filled with I's  and _'s to form a field, whenever a chip is placed, it is replacing a _.
I have already checked for a win on the horizontal and vertical ways, now I am trying to check the diagonal ways, but because they work in a different way having multiple combinations that can lead to a win even tho the chip is in the same position, I wanted to check all combinations at once.
Starting with bottom left to top right, I wrote down all the indexes I have to check, but I can't find an efficient way to keep the number of for loops under like 5 or 6, then I would have to use another 5 or 6 loops for bottom right to top left. The combinations for bottom left to top right are the following:

```
    //3,1 2,3 1,5 0,7
    //4,1 3,3 2,5 1,7 0,9
    //5,1 4,3 3,5 2,7 1,9 0,11
    //5,3 4,5 3,7 2,9 1,11 0,13
    //5,5 4,7 3,9 2,11 1,13
    //5,7 4,9 3,11 2,13
```

does anyone know how I could loop over these indexes efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Checking all the indexes doesn't seem to be the best, especially since it doesn't scale when size of the board increases (if you ever need that). You only need to check if the newly added chip gives a player the win.
So if I place a chip you have to check at most x+3, x-3, y+3, y-3, and diagonally - in total 24 squares.

P.S. not sure what indexes you supplied mean

Comment: Sorry, I think I should've further explained the game in general. The Indexes are part of the board, and they are in spacings of 2 because there is a I inbetween them everytime.

I have thought about what you said, but how should I avoid an out of bounds error? Is there a good way to check if the supplied index is in bounds of the array, or do I just use try and catch? Also I don't need to upscale the board, which is the reason I even considered checking all possibilities in the first place, since it would probably be slower than other ways, but my board really isn't too big.

Comment: Of course, you just check that whatever index you're currently checking is in range of [0, length - 1], where length is array.length or array[i].length depending on what you're checking exactly.

Also from what I understand, you seem to be storing the whole board in the array. It's better only to have an array of 7-by-6, which would store 1, 2 or an empty character. Then when you want to draw a board you can add whatever you want around each output square, you don't have to store |_| in array for that purpose.

Comment: I was just trying to implement it, you said I should check x+3, x-3, y+3,  and y-3, when you wrote that did you mean I should do it in a for loop? I guess I would need to iniciate two variables in the for loop for it to work, because I need to go one up and one to the right for example, but do you think I can use one for loop for multiple directions, or would I need 4 for loops?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it I guess I could use one for ascending diagonal and one for descending diagonal